# No-unused-expressions error keeps recurring at script import in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Complete error:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions
```

The error comes from this line of code, the import statement

```
componentDidMount() {
    import('./app/js/cursor')
  }
```

Was looking for common cases and suggested solutions are to add rules to ESLint config, but did not work for me.

Somebody ideas why this error keeps occurring?

Also, script import in a different way such as below is no solution

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "./app/js/cursor";
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Because this returns me the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding return before import. And why are you not importing this on the top of the file?

Comment: Did you need try to assign the imported file to a variable? e.g `const cursor = import('./app/js/cursor')`? Also, please import on the top of your file

Comment: Putting import into variable did the trick! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to import anything inside componentDidMount() as far as I know. Put your import on top of the file. I think the error here is correct as you are trying to call a function to import that file and you are not supposed to do it inside componentDidMount(). The other import is not React related but pure JavaScript solution so it doesn't work here. Or it could, but I don't recommend doing it. Just move your import on top of the file.